# How can itertools.chain be used with a generator function?

Tags: python

In what follows, I am trying but failing in getting a flat list:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> 
>>> def foo():
...     for i in range(3):
...         yield range(5)
... 
>>> 
>>> chain(foo)
<itertools.chain object at 0x7fce499934d0>
>>> 
>>> list(chain(foo()))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> 
>>> list(chain([foo()]))
[<generator object foo at 0x7fce49994aa0>]
>>> 
>>> list(chain(list(foo())))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get a flat list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` using itertools.chain?

Comment: You need [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close, you can use `chain.from_iterable` from `itertools`

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(foo()))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: haaaa I must say thanks, I guess there is some technical constraint that prevents doing it directly....

Comment: `chain` concatenates the arguments you pass to it, not the iterables *produced* by the arguments.